# Handle dynamic select components in state

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to handle dynamic React Select components that are coming from props and set their values into state and handle their change event to update the state. My code works but i am wondering if this is the correct approach in function updateItem to do this. I am pasting my component code below.

```
export default class Test extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        filters:[],
    };

    this.handleFilterUpdate = this.handleFilterUpdate.bind(this)
    this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this)
}

updateItem(id, itemAttributes) {
    const index = this.state.filters.findIndex(x=> x.key === id);
    if (index === -1) {
        this.setState( {filters: [...this.state.filters, {key: id, value: itemAttributes.value}]})
    } else {
        this.setState({
            filters: [
                ...this.state.filters.slice(0, index),
                   Object.assign({}, this.state.filters[index], {key: id, value: itemAttributes.value}),
                ...this.state.filters.slice(index + 1)
            ]
        });
    }
}

handleFilterUpdate(control,obj){
    this.updateItem(control, obj)
}

renderFilters(settings, controls){
    return controls.map((control) => (

        <Select
            id={control.key}
            name={control.name}
            options={control.choices}
            clearable={false}
            onChange={this.handleFilterUpdate.bind(this, control.key)}
        />
    ));
}

render() {
    return (
            {this.renderFilters(this.state.filters, this.props.filters)}
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `setState(oldState => newState)` when new state is based on old values:

```
updateItem(id, itemAttributes) {
    this.setState(oldState => {
        const index = oldState.filters.findIndex(x=> x.key === id);
        if (index === -1) {
            return {filters: [...oldState.filters, {key: id, value: itemAttributes.value}]};
        } else {
            return {
                filters: [
                    ...oldState.filters.slice(0, index),
                       Object.assign({}, oldState.filters[index], {key: id, value: itemAttributes.value}),
                    ...oldState.filters.slice(index + 1)
                ]
            };
        }
    });
}
```